# In Go, is there similar feature like "f-string" in Python?

Tags: go

In Go,
is there a similar feature like "f-string" in Python?
I cannot find a simple solution like f-string.

```
#Python
name = 'AlphaGo'
print(f'I am {name}') ##I am AlphaGo
```

A best alternative solution I found on the web and from comment is

```
//Golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    const name, age = "Kim", 22
    fmt.Println(name, "is", age, "years old.") // Kim is 22 years old.
}
```

But, this is still not as simple as f-string...

Comment: i'm feeling lucky : https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/

Comment: Seems like you want [`fmt.Printf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf)

Answer (score 20):

In Go, there is no direct equivalent of f-strings in Python. However, there are a few options:

1. Simply use:

```
fmt.Printf("I am %s\n", name) // I am AlphaGo
```

---

2. Exported `Name`, use `struct`:

```
    t := template.Must(template.New("my").Parse("I am {{.Name}}\n"))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, struct{ Name string }{name}) // I am AlphaGo
```

---

3. Lower case `name`, use `map`:

```
    t2 := template.Must(template.New("my").Parse("I am {{.name}}\n"))
    t2.Execute(os.Stdout, map[string]string{"name": name}) // I am AlphaGo
```

---

4. Use `.`:

```
    t3 := template.Must(template.New("my").Parse("I am {{.}}\n"))
    t3.Execute(os.Stdout, name) // I am AlphaGo
```

---

All - [try it on The Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/HjZcqyNIk_G):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    name := "AlphaGo"

    fmt.Printf("I am %s\n", name)

    t := template.Must(template.New("my").Parse("I am {{.Name}}\n"))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, struct{ Name string }{name}) // I am AlphaGo

    t2 := template.Must(template.New("my").Parse("I am {{.name}}\n"))
    t2.Execute(os.Stdout, map[string]string{"name": name}) // I am AlphaGo

    t3 := template.Must(template.New("my").Parse("I am {{.}}\n"))
    t3.Execute(os.Stdout, name) // I am AlphaGo
}
```

Comment: This is not the actual question. Printf returns void and outputs string to console . How is it related to f-string?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The correct answer is "no, there is not an f-string equivalent in Go."